# Solving $5x=6y-4$ and $2y=3x+4$ system of linear equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm given to solve the following system of equations.

$5x=6y-4$,

$2y=3x+4$

Here's what I'm doing.
Rearranging the equations with variables on left.

$5x-6y=-4$ and $2y-3x=4$

I then solve for $y$ in the second equation.

$2y-3x=4 \therefore 2y=4+3x \therefore y = \frac{4+3x}{2}$

I plug this $y$ back into the second equation and solve for $x$

$2\left(\frac{4+3x}{2}\right)-3x=4 \therefore 4+3x-3x=4 \therefore 4=4$

It seems like my $x$ variable simply cancelled out, what does this mean?

Comment: If you solve from the second equation and put it back to the second equation, nothing happens of course.

Comment: Oh wow, what stupid mistake.

Comment: It may be easier in this case to *add* the two equations together to get $5x+2y=6y+3x$ where the constants cancel. This gives $x=\color{red}{2y}$ and since $\color{red}{2y}=3x+4$...

Comment: Why would you rearrange the second equation to collect all of the variables on one side when $y$ is already isolated? The first thing that you do when solving for $y$ after rearranging is to undo all of the work that you just did.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed as i was looking through the procedure. To answer your question; is because the book which I'm reading suggests me to "manipulate all the variables to one side of the equation". I didn't question it when I did it, but now I realise it's waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got $y=\frac{4+3x}2$ from the second equation, which is correct. And now, there's nothing more that you can get from *that* equation. Plug $y=\frac{4+3x}2$ in the *first* equation now.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the system in the form
$$5x-6y=-4$$
$$-3x+2y=4$$
Multiplying the second equation by $3$ and adding to the first we get
$$-4x=8$$ so $$x=-2$$

Comment: You basically ensure that the variable which we use to search $x$ in terms of is equalised in both equation to ensure that they're expressing same $x$ value?

Comment: Yes, in your system of equation is $x$ in both equations the same variable.